# How to hyphenate word including a dash in list of references?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

I have a concatenated word that contains a dash in the title of a biblatex entry. The problem is that I cannot add the correct hyphenations manually to the entry since Zotero seems not to allow for this (from which the .bib file gets automatically exported.) I read that LaTeX has a 'feature' that doesn't allow for words containing a dash to be hyphenated. So

```
\hyphenation{some-word-with-dash-and-hyphen}
```

won't work for hyphenating `someword-withdashandhyphen`. I am not using LuaTeX either. Am I out of options?

Comment: At some stage, you'll stop exporting the bbl file from Zotero. At that point, fix the entry.

Comment: What does Zotero do, if you add a unknown, new command, e.g. \myhyphenationpoint to the title?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I then export it to .bib it has `$\backslash$myhyphenationpoint` in the title.

Comment: Hm. I couldn't find much info about how zotero exports to bib and I'm not using it myself. Ask in some zotero forum if there is an option to protect chars from such replacements and if not I would use something else ...